# Creating a grid of Windows Phone controls (Buttons)

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm looking to create a grid of buttons to make a simple game in Windows Phone just to test out what I can do with it.

I did the exact same thing with visual C#:

```
for (int j = 0; j < down; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < right; i++)
            {
                Button b = new Button();
                b.SetBounds(i * 50, j * 50 + 30, 50, 50);
                b.Click += new EventHandler(b_Click);
                bArray[i, j] = b;                   
                Controls.Add(b);                    
            }
        }
```

I was looking to recreate this in Windows Phone, but I can't seem to figure out how. If I do the same thing, but do say 'myGrid.Children.Add(b)', it seems to just place a single button in the center, even when I specify the top and left margins.

If anyone familiar with Silverlight and could tell me how I would translate the code I did in visual C# to Silverlight, i'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your `Grid` a `WrapPanel` from Silverlight for Windows Phone 7 Toolkit and add yours buttons to this `WrapPanel`

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to make the buttons inside closer together?

Comment: Try to change parameters of SetBounds methods to SetBounds(0, 0, 50, 50)